# Задача на автоморфные числа. Язык Си

Tags: c, теория-чисел

Автоморфными называются числа, которые содержатся в последних разрядах их квадрата, например, десятичные числа: 5<sup>2</sup> = 25, 25<sup>2</sup> = 625. Автоморфные числа существуют в системе счисления, основание n которой не должно быть простым числом или его степенью (n = 6,10,12,14…). Составьте алгоритм нахождения k автоморфных чисел в заданной системе счисления.

Нельзя использовать cin,cout,bool.

Есть вот такой код(помогите его изменить так чтобы он выводил не только k чисел, но и в системе счисления заданной пользователем. И нужно убрать bool,cin,cout):

```
using namespace std;

int cnt_digit(int x); // функция подсчета количества цифр числа
bool isauthomorf(int x);//функция вычисления автоморфного числа

int main() {
    unsigned long long cnt;
    unsigned long long i = 1;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    printf("Введите количество необходимых чисел:");
    cin >> cnt;//количество нужных чисел

    while (cnt) { 
        if (isauthomorf(i)) {
            cout << i << endl; //передвижение на новую строку
            --cnt;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
bool isauthomorf(int x) {
    unsigned long long i = x;
    unsigned long long tmp = i;
    unsigned long long cnt = cnt_digit(i);
    unsigned long long del = 1; 
    unsigned long long k = 1; 
    unsigned long long b = 0; 
    unsigned long long s = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < cnt; ++j)//проверка остатка от деления
    del *= 10;
    unsigned long long copy_del = del;

    while (tmp) { //проверка числа на автоморфность
        b = i * (tmp % 10);
        tmp /= 10;
        b = (b % del) * k;
        del /= 10;
        k *= 10;
        s += b;
    }
    return ((s % copy_del) == i) ? true : false; //тернарная операция
}
int cnt_digit(int x) {
    unsigned long long cnt = 0;
    unsigned long long tmp = x;
    while (tmp) {
        tmp /= 10;
        ++cnt;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Вы что, серьезно? их перебором искать?... 8-/  Почитайте что-то типа https://parpalak.com/articles/science/automorph или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1353582/195342 (последнее не дубликат, потому что там только десятичная система счисления).

Comment: Это не мой код. Я находила еще код, который основан на теоремах, но он не работает так как мне нужно, а я не знаю как его изменить

Comment: Да, я смотрела тот вопрос. Тот код странно выводит числа, начиная не с 1. А еще там повторяются числа в ответе, я без понятия почему и что с этим делать

Comment: Вы знаете как это исправить??

Comment: @MythMath, то что вы ищите готовое решение, а не пытаетесь решить задачу самостоятельно отбивает желание вам помогать.

Comment: я прошу не решение, а хотя бы подсказку что идет не так в коде...

Comment: Две вещи: поиск перебором и ограниченный целый тип. Автоморфных чисел только два для каждого числа цифр. Ваш код перебирает 2^64 чисел чтобы напечатать  из них 38 штук. Я говорю только про алгоритм.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо Киевэнерго, пока не срубили :) Нашел. Там расчеты со спецификой, что это именно 10 (с учетом делимости и т.п.). Не придумал сразу, как одно уравнение в остатках решить (все ж таки я физик, а не математик :)), пришлось подбором сработать — времени пока нет думать и искать всерьез...

Answer (score 3):

Вот поиск всех автоморфных (без тривиальных 0 и 1) для любых систем счисления. Использовал Boost, искал очередную цифру полуподбором.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using large = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

using namespace std;

string to_sys(large n, large s)
{
    char dig[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string r;
    while(n)
    {
        r = dig[int(n%s)] + r;
        n /= s;
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const large SYS = atoi(argv[1]);
    vector<large> q;
    for(int i = 2; i < SYS; ++i)
        if (i*i%SYS == i)
        {
            q.push_back(i);
            cout << "Found " << i << endl;
        }

    unsigned long long n = 0;
    cout << "N = 0:\n";
    for(auto x: q)
    {
        printf("    x   = %20s\n",to_sys(x,SYS).c_str());
        printf("    x^2 = %20s\n",to_sys(x*x,SYS).c_str());
    }
    large tenn = SYS;
    for(n = 1; n <= 9; ++n, tenn *= SYS)
    {
        cout << "N = " << n << ":\n";
        for(auto& x: q)
        {
            large b, p = (x*x/tenn)%SYS;

            for(b = 0; b < SYS; ++b)
                if (b*(2*x-1)%SYS == (SYS - p)%SYS) break;

            x += b*tenn;
            printf("    x   = %20s\n",to_sys(x,SYS).c_str());
            printf("    x^2 = %20s\n",to_sys(x*x,SYS).c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я поняла. Буст это библиотека которую нужно отдельно скачать. А еще вопрос: так как я изучаю язык Си, а не Си++, мне нельзя использовать cout и прочее. Я ведь могу без этого обойтись?

Comment: Буст надо будет заменить рукописной арифметикой произвольной разрядности. Трудно.

Comment: препод не примет работу на c++. я уже не знаю что делать.

Comment: Писать длинную арифметику руками.

Comment: я не понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под длинной арифметикой

Comment: Число - массив цифр. Числа перемножаются в столбик.

Comment: Понимаете, здесь не принято делать полностью работу за вас. С такими вопросами — готовый код "под сдачу преподу" — вам надо обращаться на соответствующие ресурсы. Здесь в основном помощь частичная, так сказать :) — вы пришли со своей задачей, вам подсказали, что способ вы выбрали неверный, что числа надо не проверять (их ***очень*** мало), а генерировать, показали статью, где описаны эти автоморфные числа, их свойства и генерация... Приведенный выше код — просто показывает, как это можно сделать. Ваша задача может решаться и проще, но вы не привели ее полностью, со всеми ограничениями...

Answer (score 2):

### Итерации

Пусть число *D* записано в виде *d<sub>k</sub>d<sub>k-1</sub>...d<sub>2</sub>d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>0</sub>*, где *d<sub>i</sub>* - цифра в системе счисления с основанием *b*. Тогда число равно *D = d<sub>k</sub>b<sup>k</sup> + d<sub>k-1</sub>b<sup>k-1</sup> + ... + d<sub>2</sub>b<sup>2</sup> + d<sub>1</sub>b<sup>1</sup> + d<sub>0</sub>b<sup>0</sup>*.

Для возведения в квадрат используем умножение в столбик. Положим *c<sub>-1</sub> = 0*. Начиная с *k = 0* вычислим:

*s<sub>k</sub> = c<sub>k-1</sub> + (d<sub>k</sub>d<sub>0</sub> + d<sub>k-1</sub>d<sub>1</sub> + d<sub>k-2</sub>d<sub>2</sub> + ... + d<sub>2</sub>d<sub>k-2</sub> + d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>k-1</sub> + d<sub>0</sub>d<sub>k</sub>)*.

*e<sub>k</sub> = s<sub>k</sub> % b*, *c<sub>k</sub> = s<sub>k</sub> // b*. *%* - остаток от деления, *//* - деление нацело.

*e<sub>i</sub>* - *i*-тая цифра числа *D<sup>2</sup>*.

Пример: *D = 109376<sub>10</sub>*

*s<sub>0</sub> = 0 + 6·6 = 36*, *e<sub>0</sub> = **6***, *c<sub>0</sub> = 3*;

*s<sub>1</sub> = 3 + 7·6 + 6·7 = 87*, *e<sub>1</sub> = **7***, *c<sub>1</sub> = 8*;

*s<sub>2</sub> = 8 + 3·6 + 7·7 + 6·3 = 93*, *e<sub>2</sub> = **3***, *c<sub>2</sub> = 9*;

*s<sub>3</sub> = 9 + 9·6 + 3·7 + 7·3 + 6·9 = 159*, *e<sub>3</sub> = **9***, *c<sub>3</sub> = 15*;

*s<sub>4</sub> = 15 + 0·6 + 9·7 + 3·3 + 7·9 + 6·0 = 150*, *e<sub>4</sub> = **0***, *c<sub>4</sub> = 15*;

*s<sub>5</sub> = 15 + 1·6 + 0·7 + 9·3 + 3·9 + 7·0 + 6·1 = 81*, *e<sub>5</sub> = **1***, *c<sub>5</sub> = 8*;...

Продолжать пока есть цифры в *D* и *с<sub>k</sub> > 0*. Недостающие цифры заменить нулями.

Получим *D<sup>2</sup> = 11963**109376**<sub>10</sub>*. Выделены цифры, которые были вычислены выше и которые совпадают с цифрами *D*. Совпадение не случайно - для примера выбрано автоморфное число.

Можно ли дополнить *D* ещё одним разрядом чтобы получилось семиразрядное автоморфное число? Попробуем. Теперь *D = x109376<sub>10</sub>*. Первые шесть разрядов *D<sup>2</sup>* совпадают с предыдущим примером. Следующий разряд:

*s<sub>6</sub> = 8 + x·6 + 1·7 + 0·3 + 9·9 + 3·0 + 7·1 + 6·x = 103 + 2·6·x*, *e<sub>6</sub> = (103 + 2·6·x) % 10*, *c<sub>6</sub> = (103 + 2·6·x) // 10*;

*D* автоморфное, поэтому *e<sub>6</sub> = x*. Получается сравнение вида *(103 + 2·6·x) ≡ x mod 10*. Перепишем в виде *(2·6 - 1)x ≡ -103 mod 10*. Сравнение решается перебором всех цифр. Есть одно решение: *x = 7*.

*D = 7109376*, *D<sup>2</sup> = 5054322**7109376***.

В общем случае нужно будет решать сравнение *(2d<sub>0</sub> - 1)x ≡ a mod b*, где *d<sub>0</sub>* - младшая цифра автоморфного числа, а *a* - константа определяемая предыдущими цифрами *D*.

### Младшие цифры

Сравнение для младшей цифры автоморфного числа: *d<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> ≡ d<sub>0</sub> mod b*. Решается перебором всех цифр. Среди ответов всегда будут *0* и *1* и, может быть, другие цифры.

Перепишем сравнение в виде *d<sub>0</sub>(d<sub>0</sub> - 1) ≡ 0 mod b*.

Это значит что *d<sub>0</sub>(d<sub>0</sub> - 1)* делится на *b*.

Предположим что *НОД(2d<sub>0</sub> - 1, b) > 1*. Тогда существует простое *p* на которое делятся и *2d<sub>0</sub> - 1* и *b*. Так как *b* делится на *p*, а *d<sub>0</sub>(d<sub>0</sub> - 1)* делится на *b*, то *d<sub>0</sub>(d<sub>0</sub> - 1)* делится на *p*. *p* простое, следовательно или *d<sub>0</sub>* делится на *p* или *d<sub>0</sub> - 1*.

Если *d<sub>0</sub>* делится на *p*, то и *(2d<sub>0</sub> - 1) - (2d<sub>0</sub>)* делится на *p*. Тогда *-1* делится на *p*. Противоречие.

Если *d<sub>0</sub> - 1* делится на *p*, то и *(2d<sub>0</sub> - 1) - (2(d<sub>0</sub> - 1))* делится на *p*. Тогда *1* делится на *p*. Противоречие.

В обоих случаях противоречия. Следовательно *НОД(2d<sub>0</sub> - 1, b) = 1*.

Вспомним сравнение, которое мы решаем для поиска следующей цифры: *(2d<sub>0</sub> - 1)x ≡ a mod b*. Множитель при *x* взаимно прост с *b*. Тогда сравнение для любых значений *a* имеет ровно одно решение.

В итоге имеем алгоритм, который по начальной цифре строит одну единственную бесконечную последовательность старших цифр, любой префикс которых годится в качестве автоморфного числа. Других автоморфных чисел нет.

### Реализация

Программа читает базу системы счисления, отыскивает стартовые цифры кроме нуля и единицы. Для каждой стартовой цифры строит цепочку, по мере роста цепочки печатает её префиксы. Если префикс начинается с нуля, он пропускается. Числа перед печатью упорядочиваются.

Программа сама не останавливается. При вызове надо отобрать сколько нужно чисел, и остановить её. Внизу есть пример.

Автоморфные числа *0* и *1* не печатаются:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct number_t {
    unsigned long long carry;
    int k;
    unsigned *digits;
} number_t;

void number_t_resize(number_t *n, int capacity) {
    unsigned *digits = realloc(n->digits, capacity * sizeof(n->digits[0]));
    if (digits == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    n->digits = digits;
}

int compare_numbers(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const number_t *n1 = p1;
    const number_t *n2 = p2;
    assert(n1->k == n2->k);
    for (int i = n1->k - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (n1->digits[i] < n2->digits[i]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (n1->digits[i] > n2->digits[i]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int digit_width(int base) {
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = base - 1; i != 0; i /= 10) {
        ++w;
    }
    return w;
}

void print_number(unsigned base, const number_t *n) {
    const int w = digit_width(base) + 1;
    for (int i = n->k - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (base <= 36) {
            putchar("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[n->digits[i]]);
        } else {
            printf("%*u", w, n->digits[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
    unsigned base;
    if (scanf("%u", &base) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    int n_numbers = 0;
    for (unsigned d = 2; d < base; ++d) {
        if (d * d % base == d) {
            ++n_numbers;
        }
    }

    if (n_numbers == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    number_t *numbers = malloc(n_numbers * sizeof(numbers[0]));
    if (numbers == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    int number_capacity = 1;
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (unsigned d = 2; d < base; ++d) {
            const unsigned sum = d * d;
            if (sum % base == d) {
                assert(i < n_numbers);
                number_t *n = &numbers[i];
                n->digits = NULL;
                number_t_resize(n, number_capacity);
                n->carry = sum / base;
                n->k = 1;
                n->digits[0] = d;
                ++i;
            }
        }
        assert(i == n_numbers);
    }

    for (int k = 1; ; ++k) {
        qsort(numbers, n_numbers, sizeof(numbers[0]), compare_numbers);

        for (int i = 0; i < n_numbers; ++i) {
            const number_t *n = &numbers[i];
            assert(n->k == k && k <= number_capacity);
            if (n->digits[n->k - 1] > 0) {
                print_number(base, n);
            }
        }

        if (k == number_capacity) {
            number_capacity *= 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < n_numbers; ++i) {
                number_t_resize(&numbers[i], number_capacity);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n_numbers; ++i) {
            number_t *n = &numbers[i];
            unsigned long long sum = n->carry;
            for (int i = 1; i < n->k; ++i) {
                sum += n->digits[i] * n->digits[n->k - i];
            }
            for (unsigned d = 0; d < base; ++d) {
                if (sum % base == d) {
                    assert(n->k == k);
                    n->carry = sum / base;
                    n->digits[n->k] = d;
                    ++n->k;
                }
                sum += 2 * n->digits[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 automorphic-numbers.c
>
> $ echo 10 | ./a.out | head -20
> 5
> 6
> 25
> 76
> 376
> 625
> 9376
> 90625
> 109376
> 890625
> 2890625
> 7109376
> 12890625
> 87109376
> 212890625
> 787109376
> 1787109376
> 8212890625
> 18212890625
> 81787109376
>
> $ echo 30 | ./a.out | head -20
> 6
> a
> f
> g
> l
> p
> 3a
> 7f
> ap
> j6
> mg
> ql
> 13a
> 2j6
> 3mg
> q7f
> rap
> sql
> 1q7f
> b2j6
>
> $ echo 210 | ./a.out | head -20
>   15
>   21
>   36
>   70
>   85
>   91
>  105
>  106
>  120
>  126
>  141
>  175
>  190
>  196
>    5 175
>   28 196
>   46 141
>   52 105
>   75 126
>   81  91
> ```